# Get position of IHTMLElement

Tags: c#

I'm searching for a solution to get the x,y position of an IHTMLElement.
I'm using this code to get the positon of an input element and it works

```
mshtml.HTMLDocument htmlDoc = browser.Document as mshtml.HTMLDocument;
mshtml.IHTMLElement ele = htmlDoc.getElementById("input-ex");
```

in further code I'm trying to get the position of a button by tag name but I just receiver zero values offsetLeft, offsetTop, offsetParent,...

```
mshtml.IHTMLElementCollection searchElement = htmlDoc.getElementsByName      ("btnSet");

for (int i = 0; i < searchElement.length; i++)
{
  objElement = (mshtml.IHTMLElement)searchElement.item(i, 0);
  findPosX(objElement);
}

public static int findPosX(mshtml.IHTMLElement obj)
{
 if (obj == null)
       return 0;

int curleft = 0;
if (obj.offsetParent != null)
{
    while (obj.offsetParent != null)
    {
        curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
        obj = obj.offsetParent;
    }
}

return curleft;
}
```